# Redirect falha Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade, redirect

Caros,

Podem me ajudar com este redirect laravel?
Criei um método onde ele reavalia os dados e redireciona, por outro lado na hora de redirecionar recebo o erro Route [clima.consenso.visual.ID] not defined, só que eu defini as rotas.

Imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    //Redireciona
public function redirect( Request $request, Pesquisa $pesquisa )
{
    $jaFeito = Consenso::where( 'pesquisa_id', $pesquisa->id )->count() > 0;

    if ($jaFeito) {
        return redirect()->route( 'clima.consenso.visual.'.$pesquisa->id );
    }
    return redirect()->route( 'clima.consenso.show' );
}
```

Rota

```
        //Grupo consenso
    $router->group( [ 'prefix' => 'consenso', 'as' => 'consenso.' ],
        function ( $router ) {
            /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */
            $router->get( '/', [ 'uses' => 'ConsensoController@index', 'as' => 'index' ] );

            $router->get( '/pesquisa/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                'uses' => 'ConsensoController@show',
                'as'   => 'show'
            ] );
            $router->post( '/pesquisa/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                'uses' => 'ConsensoController@store',
                'as'   => 'store'
            ] );
            $router->get( '/visual/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                'uses' => 'ConsensoController@visual',
                'as'   => 'visual'
            ] );

            $router->get( '/redirect/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                'uses' => 'ConsensoController@redirect',
                'as'   => 'redirect'
            ] );
        }
    );
```

View

```
        @forelse($pesquisas as $pesquisa)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                <a href="{{ route('clima.consenso.redirect', compact('pesquisa')) }}">{{$pesquisa->id}}</a>
            </th>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('clima.consenso.redirect', compact('pesquisa')) }}">{{$pesquisa->matricula}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('clima.consenso.redirect', compact('pesquisa')) }}">{{mb_convert_case($pesquisa->nome,MB_CASE_TITLE , 'UTF-8' )}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ $pesquisa->updated_at->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
            <td>
                <button
                        type="button" class="btn">
                    <a href="{{ route('clima.consenso.show', compact('pesquisa')) }}">Avaliar</a>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está correto, a rota `clima.consenso.visual.1127` não existe mesmo. A rota existente é `clima.consenso.visual` que recebe um parâmetro `clima_pesquisa`.

[Para redirecionar uma `Response` para uma `named route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirecting-named-routes) basta usar `redirect('nome.da.rota', ['parametros' => 'da rota'])`;

No teu caso seria:

```
return redirect()->route( 'clima.consenso.visual', ['clima_pesquisa' => $pesquisa->id]);
```

Comment: Obrigado cara deu certo.